# Warning "Return makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: objective-c

Why does it have a "Return makes pointer from integer without a cast" warning?

I have a "Person" object that contains an NSString and an int.

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
Person *thePerson = [theList objectAtIndex:row];
if (tableColumn == nameTableColumn)
    {
        return thePerson.theName;
    }
    else if (tableColumn == ageTableColumn)
    {
        return thePerson.theAge;
    }
    else
         return nil;
}
```

For some kind of reason, the Age instance variable gets a warning about pointers.  It's weird and I want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is the type for a generic object, and is actually a pointer (even though you don't have to declare it with the '*'). `int` isn't an object, and so you get the warning. If you want to use this method, you could try wrapping it in an `NSNumber`:

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
Person *thePerson = [theList objectAtIndex:row];
if (tableColumn == nameTableColumn)
    {
        return thePerson.theName;
    }
    else if (tableColumn == ageTableColumn)
    {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:thePerson.theAge];
    }
    else
         return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a value type, but `id` corresponds to an arbitrary Objective-C pointer type.

You can wrap the `int` in an `NSNumber` and return that:

```
return [NSNumber numberWithInt:thePerson.theAge];
```